# Exposing a C++ class instance to a python embedded interpreter

Tags: c++, python, boost, swig, boost-python

I am looking for a simple way to expose a C++ class instance to a python embedded interpreter.

- I have a C++ library. This library is wrapped (using swig for the moment) and I am able to use it from the python interpreter
- I have a C++ main program which instanciates a Foo class from my library and embeds a python interpreter

I would like to expose my C++ world instance of Foo to the python world (and seen as a Foo class).

**Is this possible, if so, how?**

I think it's almost like in the first answer of :
[boost::python::ptr or PyInstance_New usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055443/boost-python-how-to-pass-a-c-class-instance-to-a-python-class)

**I guess this means I should use `boost.Python` to wrap my library?**

My only goal is to manipulate my C++ instance of Foo in the embedded python interpreter (not sure that it can be done with the previous method).

In fact, I already have exposed my Foo class to python (with swig).

**What I have:**

*my Foo class:*

```
class Foo{...};
```

*my wrapped library (including the Foo class) exposed to python:* so I can start the python interpreter and do something like this :

```
import my_module
foo=my_modulde.Foo()
```

**What I want:**

Having a C++ main program which embeds a python interpreter and manipulates C++ world variables.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Foo  foo;   // instanciates foo
    
    Py_Initialize();

    Py_Main(argc, argv); // starts the python interpreter
                         // and manipulates THE foo instance in it

    Py_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/) Allows you to expose c++ classes to python in a very tightly integrated way - you can even wrap them so that you can derive python classes from your c++ ones, and have virtual methods resolved to the python overrides.

The [boost python tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) is a good place to start.

---

<sub>edit:</sub>

You can create a c++ object and pass a reference to it to an internal python interpreter like this:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo(std::string const& s) : m_string(s){}
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Foo:" << m_string << std::endl;
    }
    std::string m_string;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    bp::class_<Foo, foo_ptr>("Foo")
        .def("doSomething", &Foo::doSomething)
    ;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    try {
        PyRun_SimpleString(
            "a_foo = None\n"
            "\n"
            "def setup(a_foo_from_cxx):\n"
            "    print 'setup called with', a_foo_from_cxx\n"
            "    global a_foo\n"
            "    a_foo = a_foo_from_cxx\n"
            "\n"
            "def run():\n"
            "    a_foo.doSomething()\n"
            "\n"
            "print 'main module loaded'\n"
        );

        foo_ptr a_cxx_foo = boost::make_shared<Foo>("c++");

        inithello();
        bp::object main = bp::object(bp::handle<>(bp::borrowed(
            PyImport_AddModule("__main__")
        )));

        // pass the reference to a_cxx_foo into python:
        bp::object setup_func = main.attr("setup");
        setup_func(a_cxx_foo);

        // now run the python 'main' function
        bp::object run_func = main.attr("run");
        run_func();
    }
    catch (bp::error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will consider boost.Python too. I was already aware about the boost.Python capabilities to expose C++ classes but I have a lot of legacy code to wrap. So swig looks like a better solution to me (faster ? more simple ? and more language targets)... :(

I have found one of your old answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3378195/1044695). It's still obscure :) but I feel it's what I'm looking for (not just for one instance but the global idea is here) ?

I was hoping to do that with swig and python api ? :(

Comment: I've added an example trying to answer your exact question with boost::python - afraid I can't help with swig.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I want (except it's boost.python). I have mentionned your answer as useful (very useful actually :)). I will wait a bit for other responses (especially concerning swig) and take a deeper look on your solution.

Answer (score 7):

For reference, here is how you can achieve this using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

// Define C++ class "Foo"
class Foo {
    std::string s_;
public:
    Foo(const std::string &s) : s_(s) {}
    void doSomething() { std::cout << s_ << std::endl; }
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

// Define Python module "bar" and Python class "bar.Foo" wrapping the C++ class
PYBIND11_MODULE(bar, m) {
    py::class_<Foo, FooPtr>(m, "Foo")
        .def("doSomething", &Foo::doSomething);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Create a C++ instance of Foo
    FooPtr foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("Hello, World!");

    // Initialize Python interpreter and import bar module
    PyImport_AppendInittab("bar", PyInit_bar);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import bar");

    // Make C++ instance accessible in Python as a variable named "foo"
    py::module main = py::module::import("__main__");
    main.attr("foo") = foo;

    // Run some Python code using foo
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo.doSomething()");

    // Finalize the Python interpreter
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it was the perfect fit for my case!

Comment: It seems that in those years something changed... I've been able to compile and run this using python 3.9 and the current stable pybind11, it works, but I get a crash on process exit (after PyFinalize)

Comment: @gabry Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure exactly why this code is not valid anymore, but in recent years pybind11 did add convenient facilities for embedding Python interpreter. You should be able to replace all the Py_Initialize / PyRun_SimpleString / Py_Finalize with pybind11 things like `py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; py::exec("foo.doSomething()")`. See: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

Comment: @gabry Oh, I just saw you recent answer, looks like you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but here is a solution using SWIG.

foo.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

struct Foo{
  Foo();
  Foo(std::string const& s);
  void doSomething();
  std::string m_string;
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo() {}

Foo::Foo(std::string const& s) : m_string(s) {}

void Foo::doSomething() {
  std::cout << "Foo:" << m_string << std::endl;
}
```

foo.i:

```
%module module
%{
  #include "foo.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "foo.h"
```

Generate the usual SWIG wrapper together with a runtime

```
swig -python -c++ -Wall foo.i
swig -python -c++ -Wall -external-runtime runtime.h
```

Generate the SWIG module containing `struct Foo`:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -shared -o _module.so foo_wrap.cxx foo.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

If you want to share type information across multiple modules, an argument `-DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=SomeName` can be added.

Now, here is how a C++ instance of `Foo` is passed to the interpreter

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <Python.h>
#include "runtime.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Py_Initialize();

  PyObject* syspath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
  PyObject* pName = PyString_FromString((char*) ".");
  int err = PyList_Insert(syspath, 0, pName);
  Py_DECREF(pName);

  err = PySys_SetObject((char*) "path", syspath);

  PyObject *main, *module, *pInstance, *run, *setup;

  try {
    main = PyImport_ImportModule("__main__");
    err = PyRun_SimpleString(
        "a_foo = None\n"
        "\n"
        "def setup(a_foo_from_cxx):\n"
        "    print 'setup called with', a_foo_from_cxx\n"
        "    global a_foo\n"
        "    a_foo = a_foo_from_cxx\n"
        "\n"
        "def run():\n"
        "    a_foo.doSomething()\n"
        "\n"
        "print 'main module loaded'\n");

    // Load Python module
    module = PyImport_ImportModule("module");

    swig_type_info *pTypeInfo = nullptr;
    pTypeInfo = SWIG_TypeQuery("Foo *");

    Foo* pFoo = new Foo("Hello");
    int owned = 1;
    pInstance =
        SWIG_NewPointerObj(reinterpret_cast<void*>(pFoo), pTypeInfo, owned);

    setup = PyObject_GetAttrString(main, "setup");

    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(setup, pInstance, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(result);

    run = PyObject_GetAttrString(main, "run");

    result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(run, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(result);
  }
  catch (...) {
    PyErr_Print();
  }

  Py_DECREF(run);
  Py_DECREF(setup);
  Py_DECREF(pInstance);
  Py_DECREF(module);
  Py_DECREF(main);

  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The above can be compiled by:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python2.7 main.cpp foo.cpp -o main -lpython2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023 answer**

It seems that pybind11 makes now this really easy, they have a special header for using pybind for embedding purposes and some detailed documentation:

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

pybind11 is a header only library, so this is cross-platform and does not add extra dependencies (except for the python interpreter)

Here is the code that solves the original post problem:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
    Foo(const std::string & s) : m_string(s){}
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Foo:" << m_string << std::endl;
    }
    std::string m_string;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(bar, m) {
    py::class_<Foo, FooPtr>(m, "Foo")
        .def("doSomething", &Foo::doSomething);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    FooPtr foo = std::make_shared<Foo>("Hello, World!");

    py::module::import("bar");
    py::module main = py::module::import("__main__");
    main.attr("foo") = foo;

    // Run some Python code using foo
    py::exec("foo.doSomething()");
}
```

Here is a basic `CMakeLists.txt` that can be used to setup in a cross-platform way a project that embeds python, `pybind11` is expected to be in the **external** subfolder and your source is expected to be named **test.cpp**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test_embed)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(extern/pybind11/include ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_options(test PRIVATE ${Python3_LINK_OPTIONS})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
```