# Boost Python issue with converters - static linking

Tags: python, c++, boost, embedded, converters

I have a question regarding the below code.

It's an example how to pass a custom class via shared_ptr to embedded python code and it works when boost is dynamically linked.

Unfortunately the same code with statically linked boost doesn't work with the following error message:

"No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::shared_ptr".

I don't understand why a different linking can affect type recognition of a registered converter. What am I missing?

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks,

Dominik

Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225934/exposing-a-c-class-instance-to-a-python-embedded-interpreter?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo(std::string const& s) : m_string(s){}
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Foo:" << m_string << std::endl;
    }
    std::string m_string;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    bp::class_<Foo, foo_ptr>("Foo")
        .def("doSomething", &Foo::doSomething)
    ;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    try {
        PyRun_SimpleString(
            "a_foo = None\n"
            "\n"
            "def setup(a_foo_from_cxx):\n"
            "    print 'setup called with', a_foo_from_cxx\n"
            "    global a_foo\n"
            "    a_foo = a_foo_from_cxx\n"
            "\n"
            "def run():\n"
            "    a_foo.doSomething()\n"
            "\n"
            "print 'main module loaded'\n"
        );

        foo_ptr a_cxx_foo = boost::make_shared<Foo>("c++");

        inithello();
        bp::object main = bp::object(bp::handle<>(bp::borrowed(
            PyImport_AddModule("__main__")
        )));

        // pass the reference to a_cxx_foo into python:
        bp::object setup_func = main.attr("setup");
        setup_func(a_cxx_foo);

        // now run the python 'main' function
        bp::object run_func = main.attr("run");
        run_func();
    }
    catch (bp::error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I far as I understand the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/choosing_a_boost_python_library_.html) about Boost Python linkage, it seems that the conversion registry used for automatic conversion of Python object into C++ object is not available when statically linked. I'm facing the same issue and that's a pity it is actually the case. I would have imagined at least the required converter to be bundle but I'm afraid it is not the case for some reason.

Comment: I managed to get it working by placing the python wrapper and interpreter in the same project.

Comment: Good to know ! Too sad static linkage is so badly documented...